# How to create a <button> with two stacked <span> elements all center aligned?

Tags: html, css, button

So far I have this:

**HTML:**

```
<button>
    <span class="outter">
        <span class="inner">Line A</span>
        <span class="inner">Line b</span>
    </span>
</button>

<button>
    <span class="outter">
        <span class="inner">Line X</span>
    </span>
</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #CCFFCC;
    border: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

button .outter {
    display: inline-block;
    width: inherit;
}

button:active .outter {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}

button .inner {
    display: inline-block;
    width: inherit;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Lb3htfmx/2/

But there's quite a few problems with this as you can see in the demo. Here's how I want this button to behave:

- The buttons need to be aligned between themselves, preferably without using a parent container. I have no idea why the second button dropped a bit since they are inline elements.
- The text is not correctly aligned to the middle. I also have no idea why this is happening. If you click the button, you'll see the problem more clearly.
- When you click the button, I want a shadow and the whole button background darker. I want to avoid specifying a dark color with opacity, I really want to use some sort of darken filter (similar to what I did).

How can I fix these problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) To align the buttons, use `vertical-align: top;` on the button selector.

2) To center the text, set the the width on the `.outer` elements to `width:100%;`.

3) To make the shadow background cover the entire button, change the selector from `button:active .outter {...}` to `button:active {...}`.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cmd3nbz0/

Comment: 1) I have the same question as I wrote in another comment, why do I need that exactly? The buttons are already inline, why do they get unaligned just because the number of spans is different between the buttons (they will be aligned if there's always 1 or 2 spans for all buttons). 2) The text is not perfectly aligned, it's a bit to the right... 3) You are replacing the green background color with a black background with opacity, that's not what I want, I want a transparent black on top of the green background.

Comment: @RicardoAmaral 1) [Here is some detailed info on vertical-align](https://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/) 2)[They look centered to me...](http://i.imgur.com/RIT2UEY.jpg) 3) You can use `background-image:linear-gradient` on the `active` state to do that: http://jsfiddle.net/eLcc3ze8/

Comment: 1) Thanks. 2) I just noticed it's working only on Chrome, not on Firefox (my main browser). 3) EXACTLY WHAT I WANTED. Awesome \o/ Thanks.

Comment: @RicardoAmaral Ah, I see it now in FF. For the centering issue, change the width on `.outer` from `inherit` to `100%` This also makes the `padding` setting on the `button` selector unnecessary.

Comment: Well, the `.outer` element was only there for me trying to achieve the darken filter effect, with your `linear-gradient` solution, I was going to remove that outter span...

Comment: @RicardoAmaral If that's the case, apply the 100% width to the `.inner` spans then

Answer (score 2):

To get those buttons top aligned, you should set `vertical-align:top`, you should also to get rid of the default `:focus` outline, and see the following demo for the other parts.

```css
button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #cfc;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
}
button span {
    display: block;
}
button:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
button:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
button:active {
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}
button:active:after {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
```

```html
<button>
    <span>Line A</span>
    <span>Line b</span>
</button>

<button>
    <span>Line X</span>
</button>
```

**Fiddle demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/3vh6cuns/

Comment: The background and shadow bits are not very clear, you can leave you comments if you need further tweaks.

Comment: For the buttons alignment, I had reached the same conclusion but with `vertical-align: middle` on the `button` class, but I have 2 questions: a) Why do I need this property on the button itself, they are already inline, why do they become unaligned? If I have the same number of `<span>`s inside the button for all buttons, they are perfectly aligned. Why do I still need `vertical-align`? b) Does it make a difference between `top` and `middle` in this case? What's the recommended one?

Comment: As for the background and shadow, yeah, they don't look how I want them. Background: I want a specific color for the background (green in the example) than imagine and black background but with 0.15 of opacity on top of that green. What you did was replace the green with black and a specific opacity, but I want something transparent on top of another color. As for the shadown, it should be inset/inside on the top border, not outside like the snippet.

Comment: @RicardoAmaral You should apply the `inline-block` to the `button` no the `span` inside, as you want to align the buttons. `vertical-align:top` should be the right one if the buttons are in different height you'll see, however, you defined the height of button, so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @RicardoAmaral I just updated the answer to make the shadow inset, i understand what you're saying, but the easiest way would be define the background on the button itself, rather than put a layer on top. I tried it but it shows unwanted frame inside the button. I also added a fiddle demo so you can play around.

Comment: Defining the background on the button itself does not achieve the effect I want, which is a darken filter on top of the button color. Otherwise I have to specify exactly the color code I need and I don't want that :(

Comment: @RicardoAmaral I think I got it sorted out, see the updated answer again, also remove unnecessary html tags, classes etc, moved all into css. demo - http://jsfiddle.net/3vh6cuns/

Comment: That's a nice solution but unfortunately I can't use `content` because of minimum browser requirements. I have solved all my problems with a mix of solutions from this question, so thanks for your input.

Comment: @RicardoAmaral really!? you've already used `inline-block`, `rgba`, `box-shadow` then you suddenly couldn't use `:after` http://caniuse.com/#search=pseudo-elements anyway, you've got an answer it's even using `linear-gradient`. http://caniuse.com/#search=linear-gradient

Comment: Well, I double checked and you're right, I can use it... I think I was misinformed by a colleague and I'll have to clarify that with him tomorrow, I also misinterpreted my search results when I tried caniuse (before your comment).

Comment: I'll check with him tomorrow and maybe change my accepted answer :)

Comment: @RicardoAmaral i don't mind which one you accepts, i was totally confused, and just commenting on "minimum browser requirements" you said.

Comment: Like I said, I misinterpreted the results on caniuse. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue: Jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lb3htfmx/8/)

Your issue was that you was display your buttons as `inline-block`, when they should be `display:inline` for vertical alignment.

Documentation for vertical alignment [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp):

And You also should `float` the objects inside the button left in order to get them to "stack"

Documentation for float [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp):

and also change `button:active .outter` .outter to `button:active`

```
button:active {
  -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #000000;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
   box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 5000px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
```

Sorted the alignment issue, you shouldn't use `width:inherit;` instead use `width:100%;`

Comment: I'm sorry but to me it doesn't look fixed. Buttons are still not aligned between themselves, text doesn't seem perfectly aligned and the active state is not working.

Comment: updated active state, will work on alignment and update answer

Comment: Sorry, but it still doesn't look good to me. The shadow should be inset/inside and the background it not changing to a darker color. Maybe I'm not making myself clear on what I'm trying to achieve..

Comment: sorted it made the box shadow inset, see updated fiddle

Comment: sorted the background colour using a filter, updated full answer should be what you're expecting hopefully

Comment: Almost. You used the shadow to achieve the filter I wanted but with that, the button doesn't have the shadow I really need. I think @DrydenLong solution for that problem works best :)

Comment: I have solved all my problems with a mix of solutions from this question, so thanks for your input.

Comment: No problem at all. Whatever is the most sufficient solution for you to follow. Glad to of helped.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood what you want. Something like this?

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Aramil/Lb3htfmx/7/)

It HAS a parent container, maybe it could be done without it, but I think this is the most "Correct" way.

```css
.container {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.container > button {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    background-color: ocre;
    color: brown;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
.container > button > span {
    display: block;
}
.container > button:hover {
    border: 2px solid gray;
    color: red;
}
.container > button:focus {
    border-color: black;
    color: red;
    background-color: gray;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #888888;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <button>
        <span class="inner">Line A</span>
        <span class="inner">Line b</span>
    </button>
    <button> 
        <span class="inner">Line X</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Those attempting this in 2021 may prefer to stick a "display: flex" on the button, put child span elements inside the button element (I just now realized you could do this) and then mess with Flexbox settings until the fit is just right.